# Data Annotations RegularExpressionAttribute with empty/null

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, data-annotations

I'm using `RegularExpressionAttribute` to validate a property. The property needs to allow `anything but zero length string, null, or (just) spaces`. The regular expression I am using is `"^(?!^ *$)^.+$"`.

If the value is `null` or `an empty string`, `RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid` always returns true but I believe it should be false (just spaces works fine).

I'm no regex expert but I believe the expression is ok (If I validate the regex directly from my code using `Regex.IsMatch` the empty string returns false - as expected). Is this an issue with RegularExpressionAttribute?

(I know RequiredAttribute would ordinarily be a quick but not an option in this case)

**Updated:**

To remove any ambiguity, here is a simple chunk of test code to demonstrate:

```
    public class MyValueTester
    {
//      internal const string _REGEX_PATTERN = "^(?!\\s*$).+$";
//      internal const string _REGEX_PATTERN = @"^(?!\s*$)";
        internal const string _REGEX_PATTERN = @"[^ ]";



        public MyValueTester()
        {
            ProperValue = "hello";
            NullValue = null;
            SpaceValue = " ";
            LeadingSpaceValue = " hi";
            EmptyValue = "";
        }

        [RegularExpression(_REGEX_PATTERN, ErrorMessage = "To err is human")]
        public string ProperValue { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(_REGEX_PATTERN, ErrorMessage = "To null is human")]
        public string NullValue { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(_REGEX_PATTERN, ErrorMessage = "To space is human")]
        public string SpaceValue { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(_REGEX_PATTERN, ErrorMessage = "To empty is human")]
        public string EmptyValue { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(_REGEX_PATTERN, ErrorMessage = "To lead is human")]
        public string LeadingSpaceValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Test Code:

```
        MyValueTester myValueTester = new MyValueTester();

        ValidationContext validationContext = new ValidationContext(myValueTester);
        List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        Debug.WriteLine("=== Testing pattern '" + MyValueTester._REGEX_PATTERN + "' ===");

        var expectedResults = new[]
                            {
                                new {propertyName = "ProperValue", expectedPass = true},
                                new {propertyName = "LeadingSpaceValue", expectedPass = true},
                                new {propertyName = "NullValue", expectedPass = false},
                                new {propertyName = "SpaceValue", expectedPass = false},
                                new {propertyName = "EmptyValue", expectedPass = false},
                            };

        bool isMatch = Validator.TryValidateObject(myValueTester, validationContext, validationResults, true);

        foreach (var expectedResult in expectedResults)
        {
            ValidationResult validationResult = validationResults.FirstOrDefault(r => r.MemberNames.Contains(expectedResult.propertyName));
            string result = expectedResult.expectedPass ? (validationResult == null ? "Ok" : "** Expected Pass **") : (validationResult != null ? "Ok" : "** Expected Failure **");

            Debug.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", expectedResult.propertyName, result);
        }
```

And results for the pattern suggestion so far:

```
=== Testing pattern '^(?!\s*$).+$' ===
ProperValue: Ok
LeadingSpaceValue: Ok
NullValue: ** Expected Failure **
SpaceValue: Ok
EmptyValue: ** Expected Failure **

=== Testing pattern '^(?!\S*$)' ===
ProperValue: ** Expected Pass **
LeadingSpaceValue: ** Expected Pass **
NullValue: ** Expected Failure **
SpaceValue: Ok
EmptyValue: ** Expected Failure **

=== Testing pattern '^(?!\s*$)' ===
ProperValue: ** Expected Pass **
LeadingSpaceValue: ** Expected Pass **
NullValue: ** Expected Failure **
SpaceValue: Ok
EmptyValue: ** Expected Failure **

=== Testing pattern '[^ ]' ===
ProperValue: ** Expected Pass **
LeadingSpaceValue: ** Expected Pass **
NullValue: ** Expected Failure **
SpaceValue: Ok
EmptyValue: ** Expected Failure **
```

Comment: Try this ^(?!\S*$).+

Comment: You must be matching the start of string once only, try `"^(?!\\s*$).+$"`.

Comment: Whats wrong with just using the `[Required]` attribute?

Comment: Does [`^(?!\s*$).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/xD4lK3/1) work for you? And really, what is wrong with the [\[Required\] attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Why is the `[Required]` attribute not an option?

Comment: Ok, I've tried both expressions, neither get me any further unfortunately. Results below (I'm expecting isvalid=false for empty string and isvalid=true for the 'somestring' value).


[Value:somestring] Pattern: '^(?!\s*$).+$' RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid:True Regex.IsMatch:True
[Value:]  Pattern: '^(?!\s*$).+$' RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid:True Regex.IsMatch:False


[Value:somestring] Pattern: '^(?!\S*$).+' RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid:False Regex.IsMatch:False
[Value:]  Pattern: '^(?!\S*$).+' RegularExpressionAttribute.IsValid:True Regex.IsMatch:False

Comment: (sorry doesn't format well in a comment!)

Comment: For future readers: the problem with using the `Required` attribute is that getting user-friendly text to appear as model validation error messages now requires copy/pasting that whole string into two attributes. This is messy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Frustrating Answer:
I was convinced there was a bug in RegularExpressionAttribute after failing to get the simplest of patterns to work, despite working fine in RegEx, etc. It turns out the data annotations validator is dumbed down the implementation of RegEx, to stop newbie errors. [MSDN has this comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute):

> If the value of the property is null or an empty string (""), the
> value automatically passes validation for the
> RegularExpressionAttribute attribute. To validate that the value is
> not null or an empty string, use the RequiredAttribute attribute.

So technically not a bug - just a poor idea. The fix, in my case, is to write a RegularExpressionAttribute extension to handle nulls/empty's (which I might do by just using a proper regex to validate in RegularExpressionAttribute::IsValid.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be that complicated. Not sure I understand the complete requirements, but doesn't just `"[^ ]"` work?

Comment: Correct, it shouldn't be complicated at all! Alas, no that pattern doesn't work.